# Example Cron with Django

Tags: python, django, cron, scheduled-tasks

I've searched the internet for a working example of a scheduled job in Django. But I can only find how to do it, but no example is given. Can someone share a working example of the Django framework running a scheduled task with cron?

Comment: What examples do you need? You already have the full instructions on making management commands, and cron itself is well documented. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: @DanielRoseman In the django documentation it is said how to create custom commands, but what I need is to make the scheduled task run when I invoke the "python manage.py runserver". Also with the other two modules I'ved posted, I've followed their instruction in ther corresponding official sites and it doesn't apparantly work

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. What's the link between scheduling and runserver? (Completely aside the fact that runserver is for development only.) Plus, if you get errors from trying something, you should post them.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm getting no errors, that's why I can't debug. Currently I'm testing the application with "runserver". And I want to keep on testing but now I want to add a scheduled task. I want that task to begun when the application is launched, aka when the "runserver" comand is invoked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all create a [custom admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/). This command will be used to add the task to the crontab. Here is an example of my custom command:

cron.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
import os
from crontab import CronTab

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Cron testing'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        pass

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        #init cron
        cron = CronTab(user='your_username')

        #add new cron job
        job = cron.new(command='python <path_to>/example.py >>/tmp/out.txt 2>&1')

        #job settings
        job.minute.every(1)

        cron.write()
```

After that, if you have a look at the code below, a python script is going to be invoked every 1 minute. Create an `example.py` file and add it there the functionality that you want to be made every 1 minute.

All is prepared to add the scheduled job, just invoke the following command from the project django directory:

```
python manage.py cron
```

To verify that the cron job was added successfully invoke the following command:

```
crontab -l
```

You should see something like this:

```
* * * * * <path_to>/example.py
```

To debug the example.py, simply invoke this coomand:

```
tail -f /tmp/out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try to add the following code block at the beginning of your python script which uses anything of the django app.

```
import sys, os, django
# append root folder of django project
# could be solved with a relative path like os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..') which corresponds to the parent folder of the actual file.
sys.path.append('/path/to/django-project/')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
django.setup()
```

Then you should be able to call this script in a cronjob like

```
* * * * * user /path/to/python /path/to/script
```